# AVAudioEngine API: AVAudioUnitTimePitch too much CPU usage

Tags: ios, cpu-usage, avaudioengine, pitch-shifting

I am trying to implement a simple drum pads machine application with **pitch shifting** filter. I am using **AVAudioEngine API**.

There are **12** pads in app. Each pad has own class with its own **AVAudioPlayerNode**. When there are no other filters connected, the app is working pretty fast. Almost without any delay.
But when I am trying to attach **AVAudioUnitTimePitch** to the chain, the **CPU** usage rises up to 100% and the app hangs up after initialization. Was tested on **iPad3**. 
This code goes for each Pad initialization.

```
_playerNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
_pitchFilter = [[AVAudioUnitTimePitch alloc] init];

[_audioEngine attachNode:_playerNode];
[_audioEngine attachNode:_pitchFilter];

[_audioEngine connect:_playerNode to:_pitchFilter format:_buffer.format];
[_audioEngine connect:_pitchFilter to:_audioEngine.mainMixerNode format: _buffer.format];
```

Is there a way to reduce CPU usage somehow?
P.S. Also I tested this app on **iPad Air**. And it works. But the CPU usage still is pretty high: **25-30%** after init. And about **50%** while playing audio.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of processing here... Try reducing the sample rate, channel count or bit depth. AFAIK there isn't a way to change the buffer size for AVAudioEngine.